# Error 500 on .htpassword, page doesn't display after login

Tags: html, .htaccess, hosting, cpanel

I've tried for hours to get .htaccess and .htpassword to work for a specific part of my website.

Here's the code for .htaccess

```html
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Welcome. Please Enter Your Password."
AuthUserFile /public_html/assets/testprivate/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

And here's the code used for the .htpasswordfile

```html
username:encryptedpassword
```

The password box appears but I don't know why once it is entered the page doesn't appear?

Can someone please help me. Is there also a way that I could make it so that only certain users can view the page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must look in Apache's error log to find details on the 500 error. It could be practically anything, but a distinct possibility is that the htpasswd file is unreadable or has incorrect permissions.

Comment: It looks like you have the .htpasswd file inside your public document root. Althought probably not causing an error, that is not recommended. It would be more secure to place it somewhere not beneath `/public_html`

Comment: Fixed it, thank you.

Comment: You mean you fixed the insecure password file or you fixed your whole issue? If the whole issue, you could delete the question since it has no answers.